# How to get all Nfts including metadata by walletaddress

Tags: nft, metadata

I am looking for a way to get all NFTs by the wallet address. I used to use metaplex for this but it gave me some problems and I am looking for another way to do it. I can't find any good solution online so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1):

get NFTs snippet:

```
import { 
   getParsedNftAccountsByOwner, 
   isValidSolanaAddress, 
   createConnectionConfig, 
} from "@nfteyez/sol-rayz";
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';

  const [network, setNetwork] = useState(WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet);
 const connection = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

  const fetchMetadata = async (nftArray) => {
    let metadatas = [];
    for (const nft of nftArray) {
      console.log(nft);
      try {
        await fetch(nft.data.uri)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((meta) => {
            metadatas.push({ ...meta, ...nft });
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    return metadatas;
  };

  const getNfts = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const connect = createConnectionConfig(connection);
    
     if (!isValidSolanaAddress(address)) {
    
      console.log("Please enter a valid Solana address or Connect your 
      wallet");
 
      return;
    }
 
    const nftArray = await getParsedNftAccountsByOwner({
      publicAddress: address,
      connection: connect,
      serialization: true,
    });

 const metadatas = await fetchMetadata(nftArray);
 console.log(metadatas);
 return metadatas;
}
```

The returned `metadatas` have nft data you will have to show it in some fancy cards created by you. Before returning `metadatas` you can loop through to get data and show in cards created by you, example:

```
for (const nft of metadatas) {
      if (nft.data.symbol === "mysymbol") {
        //do this
      } else {
        //SKIP
      }
    }
```

on frontend side add this line:

```
 <Button onClick={getNfts}>Show NFTs</Button>
```

Also add a card component to display `metadatas` in it.