# How can I make a survey which you can only interact with if you own an nft of a certain collection?

Tags: verify, dao

looking to build a website for voting and stuff that DAOs do.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is one approach which I used earlier may not be the best solution is that you fetch all NFTs from user wallet and after getting all NFTs you filter among them based on some unique thing in metadata. In my case i filtered by a logic that if NFT has unique mint id and the nft symbol is correct and uploaded url in the metadata matches where nft is uploaded. Then after this filter I allowed this NFT to participate and later I blacklisted it so it can't be used until next voting.

Here's the code snippet on how I filtered NFTs answered by me on some other question -> [How to get all Nfts including metadata by walletaddress](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/how-to-get-all-nfts-including-metadata-by-walletaddress)

Hope this helps.